# Python Email Send to Multiple Recipients

Tags: python, email, automation, pywin32

My code doesn't have a problem. In my list of recipients, I have 10 emails adress. 
Do you know to send an email to every singles address email of this list?

Message error:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Out
look', 'Outlook does not recognize one or more names. ', None, 0, -2147467259),
None)

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
dfs = xls.parse(sheet_name="details", header = None)
recipients = dfs[21]

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = recipients
mail.Subject = 'Automatic Email '
mail.Body = 'body'
mail.HTMLBody = 'Hello, this is a test </h2>'
mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function to send a message, and then just put a for loop that says `for email in email_list: send_email(your_subject, your_message, email)`

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(subject, message, recipient):
    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)
    smtp_obj.starttls()
    smtp_obj.ehlo()
    smtp_obj.login('your_username_here', 'your_password_here')
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'your_email_here'
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    smtp_obj.quit()
```

this is my function for sending e_mail through yahoo, but it can be adapted by logging into the appropriate smtp server for your provider (I would guess outlook from your code)

Comment: Thanks but with this function the connection to Outlook doesn t work that's why I had to use win32.

Comment: if your email code already works, then I would suggest just wrapping it in a function that can easily be called repeatably

Comment: I believe that smtp for outlook is: `smtp-mail.outlook.com` and port 587. In case you mistyped it as just "smtp.outlook.com" or something similar

Comment: Do you mean by wrapping my current email code, looping in my data frame?

Comment: I would think you can wrap `mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = recipients
mail.Subject = 'Automatic Email '
mail.Body = 'body'
mail.HTMLBody = 'Hello, this is a test </h2>'
mail.Send()` into a function that takes an e-mail as an argument

Comment: Like create a function **send_mail? **

Comment: yeah that would be the easiest approach in my opinion. I don't believe you can specify an iterable for the recipient field of an smtp message